# Car sputtering and stalling when idle and going into first gear

Tags: engine, honda, maintenance

My 2005 Honda accord is starting to sputter and stall. It started all of a sudden one day and figured it might be my oil so I had it changed since it was time anyway. That seemed to work fine there for a while but when I kick on my AC it will jolt and sputter in low RPM but higher RPM it seems fine.

Just today it is now really bad. Even with the AC off it has started to really sputter and stall. It will idle fine for a short period then stall out.

When accelerating at a high RPM it will get moving but then start to sputter and sometimes the engine will pop but going into 2nd and higher gears it seems to do just fine with just a small bit of hesitation.

What could this be? I did put a cold air intake in it and had to make a hole in the hose for the sensor - I'm going to put original back on ASAP. Could that have caused the problem? Could it be a clogged filter or too much dirt in the engine?

Comment: I have tried to sort formatting and readability, and removed the cost part of the question as this is so variable by location.

Answer (score 1):

I had problem with my Mazda Protege several years ago that sounds very similar to what you describe. I would have to give it a ton of gas to get it going as it would sputter out in the first two gears.

Turns out I had a slit in the air intake hose that goes from the filter to the intake - as soon as I replaced it, the problem magically went away. If you have an open hole in your air intake hose, I'd say that definitely could be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

When you turn the AirCon on, the AirCon compressor activates. This is seen as a load on the engine by the system electronics. The system reacts to the load by increasing the RPM of the engine, whilst at idle, by its Idle Control Valve. The way to go is a scan of the system to make sure it is working properly electronically, and a check of the compressor. The compressor may be seizing and causing an excessive load on the engine. What, when, and why you have incorporated an extra sensor into the system is unclear, but if your fault symptoms developed after its fitment then it very well may be your problem.